# Hot chemistry question on main SE page doesn't show the new Chem.SE logo

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I was just browsing the hot questions on the [main SE page](http://stackexchange.com/) and I came across a chemistry question and the logo to the left of the question text showed the beta logo not the new logo assigned on graduation.

[image]

I would think that the logo would have gotten updated everywhere in the SE network and so this is a possible bug. Please fix this.

Comment: Weird, it shows up for me. http://i.imgur.com/Qk4kADR.png

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I just saw it again. It just shows the beta logo for me. Truly weird.

Comment: I'm guessing there's some sort of caching of the images and it will eventually change. It took a day or so for it to show up for me. Definitely it's better to post here in case they can fix it.

Comment: SE's assets are aggressively cached; clear it to see the new logo. Or just wait a bit and it should happen automatically.

Comment: I believe @ManishEarth is right. This is a network caching issue that should resolve on it's own soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers This means this is also the case for the logos shown in chat feed items? Please see [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/feed-item-in-chat-doesnt-show-the-new-chem-se-logo)